# sed append something in end of the specific match line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have this file containing following text.

```
200.200.200.253
80/tcp:filtered:http
443/tcp:filtered:https

200.200.200.254
80/tcp:filtered:http
443/tcp:filtered:https

web.example.com (200.200.200.250)
80/tcp:filtered:http
443/tcp:filtered:https
```

I want to use **sed** to add (:) in end of the IP addresses. so it will look like following.

```
 200.200.200.253 :
 80/tcp:filtered:http
 443/tcp:filtered:https

 200.200.200.254 :
 80/tcp:filtered:http
 443/tcp:filtered:https

 web.example.com (200.200.200.250) :
 80/tcp:filtered:http
 443/tcp:filtered:https
```

I am having issue with `web.example.com (200.200.200.250)` regex match.

I want this line look like  `web.example.com (200.200.200.250) :`

---

I got answer this is what i tried.

```
 sed -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}/&:/' file.txt
```

Comment: depending on your file, `sed -e 's/^[0-9.]\+$/& :/'` might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$/& :/g' filename
```

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+.*/& :/g' filename
```

Comment: what about this string    web.example.com (200.200.200.250)

Comment: your sed working but not with this match web.example.com (200.200.200.250)

Comment: Satish - I have updated my answer based on your update (as you have added new data). Updated solution should work...

Comment: Ah!!! i am sorry i was running your test against wrong file.. My fault.. sorry boss. you got it right..:)